# setFilterExpression not giving results because of space?

Tags: pyqgis, expression, definition-query

I am trying to select data based on QgsVectorLayer() getting it's features from layer.getFeatures().next() method.

When I pass expression in that using QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression) where NAME column contains a space, like

```
NAME = 'ABC XYZ'
```

the filter doesn't return any rows, even when such value is present. 
When I pass

```
NAME = 'DEF'
```

It works fine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's the data provider? Can you share more of your code (a self contained snippet would be helpful)